# jQuery to change value of input issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the value of a jQuery input from my chrome extension. It wasn't working so now I am in the chrome dev tools console.

If I type `$('.upload-section__input').value`, the console returns the value of the input field as expected.  However, if I try to modify the field using:

```
 $('.upload-section__input').attr('value', 'hello world');
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function(…)`

If I try `document.getElementById(".upload-section__input").value = "My value";`

I get the error `VM219:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null(…)`

If i try `$('.upload-section__input').val("jo")`
I get the error `VM228:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function(…)`

Could someone please tell me what is causing this problem?

Comment: Edit: Wait... did you include jQuery???

Comment: The document.getElementsByClassName() returns a [ ].  If I had a .val() to the end of it, I get a 'not a function' error.  What franko said is what I tried, and does not work.

Comment: Either you haven't loaded jQuery, or you've loaded some other library that has redefined `$`.

Comment: What happens if you change `$(` to `jQuery(`?

Comment: That worked.... why did that work?

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you need to do that:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.upload-section__input').val('hello world');
});

</script>
```

The way you are doing, you are setting a property.

Comment: I have tried that, I get VM266:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function(…)

Comment: You need to have jquery installed to use this.

Comment: I do. I use jQuery with no problem throughout my app. Also I can do $('.upload-section__input').value -> returns value. So jQuery is clearly working

Comment: Have you wrapped the code in a document ready function, and placed this after your are loading jquery?

Comment: @Franco That won't fix this error. if jQuery is properly loaded, you won't get an error if the selector can't find the element, it just won't do anything.

Comment: It seems like your element you are referencing to, do not exist. Or has a different name I see a double `__` in the selector are you sure this is correct and that is a class?

Comment: This error say taht the element can not be found: `Cannot set property 'value' of null(…)`. So you can not set its value that's why ypu get this other error: `$(...).val is not a function(…)`

Comment: the selector finds the element. if I do $('.upload-section__input').value, the console returns the value

Comment: Do you mind to post the `html` form where this element is. What I did is the usual way to set the value of an element in jquery, so something is wrong somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar for solving.  Need to use the `jQuery('.classname')` tag. For some reason the `$(` tag isnt working in that specific case.

Comment: @Barmar also pointed out the reason, you must've loaded a library that also defines `$` as a function, but doesn't perform the same things as jQuery - like MooTools or Prototype (or a custom function, but you'd probably remember doing that).

Comment: That's the reason why I have asked him to put the code directly after jquery was loaded! Maybe he didn't understand what I was trying to do.